# How do I get WebStorm to correctly see a packages functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, joi

I have tried everything I can think of to get WebStorm to include the JOI package in my node.js project without throwing inspection warnings when I use its function. It works fine the way I have it written and causes no runtime errors. I have tried updating it, as well as explicitly installing it in "Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries"

All of my other libraries I have installed through NPM behave fine and do not cause any inspector errors. However a simple statement liek

`joi.string()`

Causes an "**Unresolved function or method string()**" warning

How do I get rid of this? I have a whole file of validation so ignoring this line by line is not an options.

I have tried this with both the older and latest version of joi. The older version looks as follows:

```
const joi = require('joi');
const format = joi.string();
```

The newer version is:

```
const joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const format = joi.string();
```

Both behaved the exact same way within WebStorm and raised an inspection warning.

Comment: Which `@hapi/joi` version are you using? And please tell us how you are importing `@hapi/joi`? Thanks

Comment: @a1300 - Good question. I tried both the older version and lates hapi version. Both raised the same warning in WebStorm. I edited the question to include these details.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible Solution

I found the following github issue: [DefinitelyTyped#35440](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/35440) that should be related to your problem.

Please install the newest `@types` for the `@hapi/joi` package with:

```sh
npm install --save @types/hapi__joi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. It seemed like from what I read, this was to fix the library not working at all, vs fixing inspector warnings.